# What's wrong in my PHP code? I'm using Wordpress Astra Theme and I can't insert data into my SQL

Tags: php, database, mysql, contextual-help

```
        <form method="post" action="functions.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="customer" name="Customer Name" type="text" placeholder="Customer name" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="business" name="Business Name" type="text" placeholder="Business name" class="form-control input-sm" required=""></br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="machines" name="Machines" type="text" placeholder="Enter Machines" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="price" name="Price" type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="phone" name="Phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="date" name="Date" type="text" placeholder="Date" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="address" name="Address" type="text" placeholder="Address" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" name="submitbbtn">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


            if(isset($_POST["submitbbtn"])){
                echo 'One customer added';
                $host="localhost:3306";
                $username="fartuna_wp947";
                $password="";
                $databasename="fartuna_wp947";
                //connect db
                $connect=mysql_connect($host, $username,$password);
                $db=mysql_select_db($databasename);
                
                global $wpdb;
                $DB = $wpdb->prefix."books";
                $wpdb->insert(
                    $DB,
                    [
                        'customer'  => 'customer',
                        'business'  => 'business',
                        'machines'  => 'machines',
                        'price'     => 'price',
                        'phone'     => 'phone',
                        'date'      => 'date',
                        'address'   => 'address'
                    ]
                    );
            }
```

Comment: `$wpdb` is for the current WordPress DB object connected to the current connection, your `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` calls have nothing to do with `$wpdb` ( and directly calling the mysql functions is extreme bad practice ). If you want to connect to a separate remote database and insert data then you need a _new_ and separate WPDB object.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need connection info when using the global `$wpdb`.  It's already connected.

Second, if your insert is failing, then the first thing to check would be your data format. If you don't specify a format, then it is handled as a string.  See the docs for [`WPDB::insert`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/):

> An array of formats to be mapped to each of the value in $data. If string, that format will be used for all of the values in $data. A format is one of '%d', '%f', '%s' (integer, float, string). If omitted, all values in $data will be treated as strings unless otherwise specified in wpdb::$field_types.

So if your table specifies a specific format required for the column, it may fail if your insert data format doesn't match the requirement.